# Problems updating property in javascript web component constructor

Tags: javascript

I apologize for my english. Also, I'm a beginner in javascript web components.
I don't understand why the two buttons are not pointing to the same variable in the constructor. If I increase the counter works ok, but if I decrease it doesn't. Can you help me please. What am I missing. This is my code. Thanks.

```
customElements.define('x-spinner', class extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.value = this.getAttribute('value') ? this.getAttribute('value') : 0
    
}

connectedCallback() {
    if (this.firstElementChild) return

    const status_input = document.createElement('input')
    status_input.type = 'text'
    status_input.readOnly = true
    status_input.value = this.value

    const minus_btn = document.createElement('button')
    minus_btn.type = 'button'
    minus_btn.innerHTML = '&#x2796;'

    minus_btn.onclick = function() {
        status_input.value = --this.value
        // status_input.value = this.value - 1 < 0 ? 0 : this.value
    }

    const plus_btn = document.createElement('button')
    plus_btn.type = 'button'
    plus_btn.innerHTML = '&#x2795;'

    plus_btn.onclick = () => {
        status_input.value = ++this.value
    }

    this.appendChild(minus_btn)
    this.appendChild(status_input)
    this.appendChild(plus_btn)
}
```

})

Comment: `class extends HTMLElement` [is not a good idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), particularly for host objects. If you want the element to have a default value of 0, then do that in the markup: `… value="0" …`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point this to the class try console logging `this` inside the function yiu will see it points to button element not class !
..to solve this you need to use `.bind()` method to point `this` keyword to class .. checkout [MDN docs](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-bind/)

See =>

```
  minus_btn.onclick =  function() {
  // console.log(this)  // try logging to console without bind() method 
   status_input.value = --this.value
   // status_input.value = this.value - 1 < 0 ? 0 : this.value
  }.bind(this)
```

Full answer =>

**HTML**

```
  <x-spinner></x-spinner>
```

**Js**

```
  class IncDecInput extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.value = this.getAttribute('value') ? this.getAttribute('value'): 0
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      if (this.firstElementChild) return

      const status_input = document.createElement('input')
      status_input.type = 'text'
      status_input.readOnly = true
      status_input.value = this.value
      // console.log(status_input)
      const minus_btn = document.createElement('button')
      minus_btn.type = 'button'
      minus_btn.innerHTML = '&#x2796;'

      minus_btn.onclick = function() {
        status_input.value = --this.value
      }.bind(this)

      const plus_btn = document.createElement('button')
      plus_btn.type = 'button'
      plus_btn.innerHTML = '&#x2795;'

      plus_btn.onclick = () => {
        status_input.value = ++this.value
      }

      this.appendChild(minus_btn)
      this.appendChild(status_input)
      this.appendChild(plus_btn)
    }
  }

  customElements.define('x-spinner', IncDecInput)
```

Comment: @alex prezmon Welcome ! Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

`this` values in the increment and decrement functions are different:

`-` button: the click handler was declared using `function` and hence sees the button as its `this` value (because the function is called on the button).

`+` button: the click handler is an arrow function and hence sees the `<x-spinner>` object as its `this` value because it's was the lexical `this` value where the arrow function was written (the `this` value of `connectedCallback`).

Declare them both as arrow functions to get correct operation of both buttons.

**Technical Curiosity**

Why does the `function` declared minus button not generate an error when trying to decrement `this.value`?

It turns out button do have a `value` property which is

> Defines the value associated with the button’s name when it’s submitted with the form data. This value is passed to the server in params when the form is submitted. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button))

Now the button's value defaults to the empty string, `""`, which is converted to zero when treated as a number, allowing the `--` operator to work on it without error.

Mystery solved, thanks for the question!